# Spring cloud config server aws codecommit - git-upload-pack not permitted

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-codecommit, spring-cloud-config-server

I am using aws codecommit as a repo for `config-repo`

I am facing an intermittent issue with connecting to git(codecommit) backend.

When I try to connect with Git credentials it works but not with IAM access and secret key. It says `git upload pack not permitted`.

But for some time it works with IAM access and secret key and not with Git credentials vice-versa.

#### error log

```java
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.TransportException: https://git-codecommit.<region>.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<my-repo>: 
git-upload-pack not permitted on 'https://git-codecommit.<region>.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<my-repo>/'
```

As per [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#_authentication_with_aws_codecommit), it says

> If you provide a username and password with an AWS CodeCommit URI,
> they must be the AWS accessKeyId and secretAccessKey that provide
> access to the repository. If you do not specify a username and
> password, the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey are retrieved by using
> the AWS Default Credential Provider Chain.

#### Application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  profiles: dev
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        encrypt.enabled: false
        git:
          # Https
          uri: https://git-codecommit.<region>.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<my-repo>
          force-pull: true
          clone-on-start: true
          default-label: master
          searchPaths: dev, stag, prod
          # ---- IAM Access/secret ----
          #username: 'AKI***************O6'
          #password: 'Fz+*************************csJQ'
          # ---- Git credentials ----
          username: '<my-repo>-at-18*********72'
          password: '0Z0X*****************************bUB5w='

  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration
```

I was able to run the app with either of them but it stops working in meantime, I can not figure out the reason for why it's not working with IAM credentials.

#### Dependency version

- spring-boot-starter-parent: `2.3.2.RELEASE`
- spring-cloud-dependencies: `Hoxton.SR7`
- spring-cloud-config: `2.2.4.RELEASE`